# I am trying to use python and store the href element from in a list

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to store the href elements in a list but have a bit of trouble due to my limited knowledge of python.

```
import requests, bs4

url = 'https://www.hellopeter.com/spar?page=2'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

url_list = []
for detail in soup.findAll('div', attrs = {'class':'col-xs-12 review-post'}):
    for Review in detail.findAll('a', attrs = {'class':'btn btn-custom-2 btn-full-review'}):
        url_list = url_list.append(Review['href'])
```

I'm not sure what other alternatives there are to this, but I have been searching for a while.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And this is not working? Do you get an error?

Comment: What are you actually asking?

Comment: the problem is in url_list = url_list.append(Review['href']). You just want to say  url_list.append(Review['href']) (which appends the href value to the url_list (and returns None - which you are assigning to the url_list - giving your error). Let me know if it works for you

Comment: Thanks @SweetBurlap, the url_list.append(Review['href']) was indeed the issue for my purposes.

Answer (score -1):

use the lxml library

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.hellopeter.com/spar?page=2') 
# or just get the page using urllib2 library 
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
divs= tree.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "col-xs-12") and contains(@class, "review-post")]')
lst = []
for x in divs:
   lst.append(x.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "btn") and contains(@class,"btn-custom-2") and contains(@class, "btn-full-review")]/@href'))
print lst
```